# How to extract KML data from embedded Google Map

Tags: import, extract, kml

We have a [map with Ski runs](http://www.plandespistes.nl/savoie/les-trois-vallees)

I want to extract them into a KML file and then import them into Google Earth, so I can use it on my ski holiday.

Is it possible? The importing part is easy, but don't know how to get them.

Comment: The [KML displayed on a regular Google Map](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.plandespistes.nl%2Fkml%2FLes3Vallees.kml&hl=en&geocode=+&t=h&z=11)

Comment: Thank you. I can download the KML file now, but for some reason it won't display color when I load it into Google Earth on my Android device (Samsung Galaxy Note 2).

Comment: Geocodezip, HOW did you extract them?